# CSS banner image, doesn't scale beyond the parent element

Tags: css

I'm trying to style a typcial banner image for a site, so that for narrower viewports the vertical height is maintained and the image effectively stays the same size by going beyond the parent element horizontally. (I think this is fairly typical banner image behaviour - but feel free to correct me if I'm wrong).
(browser target is ie10 and up). The below incorrectly keeps the image ratio and at 100% width so that if fails to match the height of the parent.

The current html is just an img inside a div tag

```
<div class="banner">
 <img class="img-fluid" src="somepic.jpg" />
</div>
```

Where the css classes used are:

```
.banner {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 780px;
}
```

and img-fluid is a bootstrap(4) class with

```
img-fluid {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: "Narrower viewports" implies you have some media query CSS for smaller screens.  Where's that CSS?  Further, expanding beyond the left / right edges would require completely different CSS than what you've got.

Comment: Your `.banner` has a width of 100% which means it will span 100% width of its container. Your image has a max-width of 100% and height auto(default) which means your image will span at most 100% width of its parent. So it is behaving as coded, it will be 100% width and height auto. It would never go out of its container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a background-image instead, there are a couple interesting behaviours that can be used to achieve different results.

Here's my take:

```
.banner {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 780px;
    background-image:url('somepic.jpg');
    background-size:cover;
}
```

The key here is `background-size:cover;`, it will make sure the image stretches to cover the full width and height while keeping its ratio. That means on very wide screens, it will be made larger, cutting some height. But on thinner resolutions you'll get the desired output.

Comment: Thanks adding a `background-position: center;` to what you had gave me what I was looking. The current way you had it showed only the left part of the image rather than the centre, which was what I neeeded.